# ShingleFilterFactory not working as expected

Tags: solr

We were trying `ShingleFilterFactory` for one of our project but it seems it is not working.

We wanted to use `KeywordTokenizerFactory` so that value of field is not tokenized. Later we tried applying `ShingleFilterFactory`, but it does not work.

E.g "This world has everything needed" is field value. We search with "has everything needed" but it is not working.

```xml
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"> 
    <analyzer type="index">         
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="4"
         outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false" tokenSeparator=" "/>

    </analyzer>  
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="4"
         outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false" tokenSeparator=" "/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: did you check in the solr admin console...what all token are generated and getting matched with query?

Comment: Why do you want to use the `KeywordTokenizer` in the first place? this one is not intended for fields you perform queries on. It is useful for filter fields or primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

The shingle filter factory can only work if the field is first tokenized. It takes the tokens and combines them - so for example "This world has everything needed" could result in the combination of tokens: "This world", "world has", "has everything", "everything needed". If you use the keyword tokenizer, there will be no tokens to combine.

If you use more than one word in the search, I believe you need the keyword tokenizer in the query analyzer, and the standard (or whitespace) tokenizer/shingle filter factory combination in the index analyzer, for example:

```
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"> 
    <analyzer type="index">         
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="4"
         outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false">
    </analyzer>  
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```